# How to use variable from multiple constructors in one class function? - Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I'm making a simple data class with different constructors. I want to make a function accessible to both instance types without writing it twice. How can this be done?

Ex:

```
class myClass private constructor() {

    constructor(
        weather: String, 
        day: Int?
    ) : this() {
        //I can put assignment here
    }
    constructor(
        day: Int?
    ) : this() {
        //and here, but can this be done more efficiently?
    }
    val dayString: String = when(day) { //kotlin doesn't recognize 'day' variable here outside of constructors...
        0 -> "Sunday"
        1 -> "Monday"
        2 -> "Tuesday"
        3 -> "Wednesday"
        4 -> "Thursday"
        5 -> "Friday"
        6 -> "Saturday"
        else -> "Not a valid day of the week!"
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So currently `day: Int?` is just a constructor parameter and NOT an instance property.
You should declare it as `val day: Int?` in your main constructor for the `dayString` to work. This of course will work only for the primary (main) constructor and your class will look like this:

```
class myClass private constructor(val day: Int?) {

    constructor(
            weather: String,
            day: Int?
    ) : this(day) {
        //I can put assignment here
    }

    val dayString: String = when(day) { //kotlin doesn't recognize 'day' variable here outside of constructors...
        0 -> "Sunday"
        1 -> "Monday"
        2 -> "Tuesday"
        3 -> "Wednesday"
        4 -> "Thursday"
        5 -> "Friday"
        6 -> "Saturday"
        else -> "Not a valid day of the week!"
    }
}
```

If you don't what it to be like that:
 - add default value to constructors parameter like `val day: Int? = null`
 - or add internet property to hold (like `var _day: Int? = null`)

Comment: This was a simplified example. I don't want a primary constructor with just one field and only one or two variables might be shared. If one more field was added to primary (ex: message: String), I want to avoid setting the memory of that field for all instances of the secondary constructor. It doesn't seem to like setting val on constructor parameters either.

Comment: Go for the second option then and have an instance property `private var _day: Int? = null`

Comment: Thanks, that seems to do the trick. I just now realized that using constructors will require me to set class values anyway for variable access, so I am better off just creating two separate classes if they vary too much or deal with the memory overhead of extra values if they only vary by one or two values.